# Splitting columns and retaining different data sets SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column that I want to split into two and retain only the number within the column.

JU_COUNT1 it contains data like this

```
JU_COUNT1
1 BOLT 4 ATTACH
2 BOLT 2 ATTACH
3 BOLT 1 ATTACH
0 BOLT 3 ATTACH
2 BOLT 10 ATTACH
2 BOLT 12 ATTACH
```

After the query runs I want it to look like this

```
BOLT    ATTACH
1         4 
2         2 
3         1 
0         3 
2        10 
2        12
```

My SQL query looks like

```
SELECT JU_COUNT1,         
CASE
WHEN JU_COUNT1 LIKE '%ATTACH%' THEN RIGHT(JU_COUNT1, Charindex(' ', JU_COUNT1) - 1)
ELSE JU_COUNT1
END AS 'ATTACH1',
CASE
WHEN JU_COUNT1 LIKE '%BOLT%' THEN LEFT(JU_COUNT1, Charindex(' ', JU_COUNT1) - 1)
END AS 'BOLT1'
FROM [dbo].[SUPPORTSTRUCTURE]
```

I'm able to easily retain the BOLT because its the first part in the data when BOLT is present however retrieving the value for attach is alluding me.

Comment: is the data always in this format ? only `BOLT and ATTACH` or can there be other combinations ?

Comment: the data will be this format or Null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One trick you can try here would be to remove the `BOLT` and `ATTACH` text, and then substring out the data you want:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        REPLACE(REPLACE(JU_COUNT1, 'BOLT ', ''), ' ATTACH', '') AS JU_COUNT1
    FROM [dbo].[SUPPORTSTRUCTURE]
)

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(JU_COUNT1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', JU_COUNT1) - 1) AS BOLT,
    SUBSTRING(JU_COUNT1, CHARINDEX(' ', JU_COUNT1) + 1,
              LEN(JU_COUNT1) - CHARINDEX(' ', JU_COUNT1)) AS ATTACH
FROM cte;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Clever approach.

Answer (score 1):

An approach without cte is this

```
declare @JU_COUNT1 table (data varchar(20))

insert into @JU_COUNT1 (data) values  
('1 BOLT 4 ATTACH'),
('2 BOLT 2 ATTACH'),
('3 BOLT 1 ATTACH'),
('0 BOLT 3 ATTACH'),
('2 BOLT 10 ATTACH'),
('2 BOLT 12 ATTACH')

select left(data, charindex(' BOLT', data) - 1) as Bolt,
       right(replace(data, ' ATTACH', ''), len(replace(data, ' ATTACH', '')) - (charindex('BOLT', replace(data, ' ATTACH', '')) + 4)) as Attach
from @JU_COUNT1
```

result is

```
Bolt    Attach  
----    ------- 
1       4   
2       2   
3       1   
0       3   
2       10  
2       12
```